# How can I construct arithmetic-only template objects?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'm trying to learn more about metaprogramming in C++. I'm designing class `A` which has elements of type `T` where `T` is some arithmetic type. How can I construct such an object?

Here's my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
struct A {
  A<T>(T t) : t(t) {}
  T t;
};

int main() {
  A<int> a{4}, b{2};
  std::cout << a.t + b.t << '\n';
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

> error: expected ')' before 't'
>      `A<T>(T t) : t(t) {}`

I've searched around, but the error is pretty generic, so I'm not finding an exact resolution to my problem.

If it matters I'm compiling with `-std=c++14` with *gcc (Homebrew gcc 5.3.0) 5.3.0*.

Comment: Except if it is for some SFINAE, you will have better error message with `static_assert`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `<T>` from your constructor.  The constructor isn't a template, the class is.

```
template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
struct A {
  A(T t) : t(t) {}
  T t;
};
```